# Centering a list using CSS

Tags: html, css, html-lists, centering

I'm having trouble centering my navigation bar, I can see the issue but I can't really find a fix for it. Sorry I'm kind of new to CSS.

- [Header bar with inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLmR1.png)

As you can see there is a an extra block at the front of the list.
I have searched around for a fix but I can't seem to make it fit without using absolute positioning which I'd like to avoid.

Here is a jsfiddle page to show you exactly what I mean - https://jsfiddle.net/h4ay0voj/2/

HTML code:

```
<header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <ul class="menu">
        <a class="active" href="">
            <li class="selected">Link1</li>
        </a>
        <a href="">
            <li>Link2</li>
        </a>
        <a href="">
            <li>Link3</li>
        </a>
        <a href="">
            <li>Link4</li>
        </a>
        <a href="">
            <li>Link5</li>
        </a>
    </ul>
</header>
```

CSS code:

```
header{
  width:80%;
  overflow: hidden;
  color:#ffffff;
  margin-bottom:1%;
  background: #292E37;
}

header a:link {text-decoration:none;color:#ffffff;}
header a:visited{color:#ffffff;}
header a:hover{color:#292E37;}
header a.active{color:#4db8ff;font-weight:bold;cursor:default}
header h1{text-align: center;}

ul.menu{
  width:40%;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #000000;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

ul.menu li{
  display: inline;
  padding: 1%;
  transition: background 0.2s;
  padding-bottom:2.25%;
}

ul.menu li:hover{
  background:#a7afbe;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #4db8ff;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't really get your problem? You want to center the navigation bar?

Comment: Try adding `padding: 0` to `ul.menu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about other browsers, but for Chrome, you can see that `-webkit-padding-start: 40px;` is being applied.

You can just set the padding on the element to 0 like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/byj0ye8g/

Or, the best thing to do for issues like this is to use a CSS reset like here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Also, place your anchor tags inside of the list item tags, not around them.

Answer (score 0):

The width you used for the navbar was too small resulting in the "crunching-up" of the navbar. I've increased the width to 60% for the UL class menu. I updated the JSFiddle page, so you can look at it to see if that's right.

**Here's the correct code:**

```
ul.menu{
  width:60%;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #000000;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```